# Bluetooth Android app connectable to specific app only

Tags: android, bluetooth, onclick, connection

Let's suppose I have an app that needs to connect to a pc server app via bluetooth. After discovering devices I wanna be sure that the one that I choose is running the server app. If yes then connect, otherwise not.

Is there a simple way to check it? Thanks

Comment: The connection is done by your code? App know its server PC by configuration?

Comment: Yes it is my code. App doesnt have a specific pc

Comment: Unless app can identify its server in any way (server's broadcast, server PC name, ... ) I don't see a solution.